# Query into wordpress db from laravel

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have setup my main application in Laravel and set up WordPress for blog (CRUDE) operation. Installed WordPress inside `public` folder and configured database settings for 2nd database in `config/database.php` in Laravel.

The trouble I'm having is how do I query in 2nd db (WordPress). I want to show latest 3 blog post with their featured image in landing page of my Laravel app.

The main confusion is caused by one post has two rows in db (WordPress) with attribute`post_status` with values `published` for first row and `inherit` for second row. And 3 rows if featured image is set to blog post. I would be very helpful if anyone can walk through me from this problem.

Comment: Why not use the REST API to request those 3 posts? (wpdomain/wp-json/wp/v2/posts)

Comment: Do all your post has featured image?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED v3**

> First thing first: you are seeing `inherit` is because that post has
> been revised or attachment is added. So you should pick those post
> post which has `publish` status.

MySQL query to get 3 latest post is:

```
SELECT
    posts.ID AS post_id,
    posts.post_title,
    posts.post_date
FROM
    whrg_posts AS posts
WHERE
    posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND posts.post_type = 'post'
ORDER BY
    posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

---

Assuming you have set up a Model for Post and Postmeta like it is mentioned in [this tutorial][1]. We have to first get the all the post then we have to get the attachment `src` link to that post.

Add this function in your BlogPost Model

```
Public function getPostById($post_id)
{
    return BlogPost::where('ID', $post_id)
            ->first();
}
```

replace this `getPosts()` method in BlogPost Model

```
Public function getPosts()
{
    return BlogPost::with('postmetas')
            ->status()
            ->type()
            ->orderBy('post_date', 'DESC')
            ->limit(3)
            ->get();
}
```

And in your controller you can access it like

```
public function anyPostList()
{
    $postImages = []; //array to hold the featured image URL in a key value pair
    $BlogPost = new BlogPost();
    $posts = $BlogPost->getPosts();
    foreach ($posts as $post)
    {
        if (!empty($post->postmetas))
        {
            foreach ($post->postmetas as $postmeta)
            {
                //if _thumbnail_id exists then get its guid for src
                if ($postmeta->meta_key == '_thumbnail_id' && !empty($postmeta->meta_value)){
                    $thumbnail_id = $postmeta->meta_value;
                    $attachment = $BlogPost->getPostById($thumbnail_id);
                    if(!empty($attachment->guid))
                        $postImages[$post->ID] = $attachment->guid;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    $data = [
        'posts' => $posts,
        'postImages' => $postImages
    ];
    return view('test.post', $data);
}
```

To show the post in blade: *project_name/resources/views/test/post.blade.php*

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <h1>{{ $post->post_title }}</h1>
    <span>Published on : {{ $post->post_date }}</span>
    @if(isset($postImages[$post->ID]))
        <img src="{{$postImages[$post->ID]}}" width="200"/>
    @endif
    <div>
        {{ $post->post_content }}
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I haven't made any model for db tables of wordpress yet. Do I need to make model for them ? If then what kind of relation should i establish between them ?

Comment: i hunted around google and found a way to make model and relation between wordpress tables. When I query `$posts = BlogPost::orderBy('post_date', 'desc')->limit(3)->get();` i'm getting 3 rows of table with attribute `post_status` both `published` and `inherit`.But get empty collection with query `$posts = BlogPost::where('post_status','=','published')->orderBy('post_date', 'desc')->limit(3)->get(); `

Comment: @TanjaForsberg: No it is not mandatory to have Modal but it's my personal preference to have it. and you have 2 issue in your query, I have updated my answer will the correct eloquent query, please have a look.

Comment: Well I'm able to get post title and contents with model and your query but i'm unable to get featured image of blog post with relationship i had setup.

Post mode:

`protected $connection = 'mysql2';
 protected $table = 'lw_posts';

    public function meta()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Meta', 'post_id');
    }`

Meta model:
`protected $connection = 'mysql2';
    protected $table = 'lw_postmeta';

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }`

In view:

`{{ asset('blog/wp-content/uploads'.$post->meta->meta_value) }}`

Comment: And error is :`Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$meta_value `

Comment: Till now what every code I have written was all form my mind  I have't done and single line of codding; but now I have to check it form my side also. If possible can you give me a day, because I'm writing a full fledged tutorial for this might will helpful for the community in a longer run.

Comment: Looking forward to see your tutorial. Thank you :)

Comment: I have update my answer pls have a look and setup a model as said in the link; my answer is tested and working. and let me know if still have any issue.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me again. Your answer plunged me into confusion rather than solution. I'm showing blog posts in my `_blog`  partial .I've made a custom service provider to transfer data to partials. How do I implement your codes. And how do i run loop to get featured image of specific post as you have applied nested foreach looop and dumped array of featured image.

Comment: Ok so do you need a full example? With blade function an all?

Comment: Yeah if you can. I tried by injecting model directly into partial but it didn't work out.

Comment: I accomplished it by using Wordpress REST API.

Comment: @TanjaForsberg: that's grt. btw I have updated my answer also with blade function.

Comment: It's Working for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the Laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#introduction).

> Using Multiple Database Connections
>
> When using multiple connections, you may access each connection via
>   the connection method on the DB facade. The name passed to the
>   connection method should correspond to one of the connections listed
>   in your config/database.php configuration file:
>
> `$users = DB::connection('foo')->select(...);`